# Selecting from a dropdown box

Tags: javascript

I need to make sure an artist has been selected, but not sure if i should be using  "artist" or "select". I have tried both and it's not working. The code must show an alert if there is no selection.

```js
function validate() {
    
    var select_artist = document.getElementById('artist');
    if (artist == "") {
        alert("You need to choose an artist");
        return false;
}
```

```html
<div id="artist"> 
     
     <p>Select an Artist:
 
<select name="select"> 
 
        <option value="0">Choose Artist</option>
  
  
  <option value="1">Bobby Smith</option>


  <option value="2">The Vibes</option>


        <option value="3">Kids of Rock</option>

</select>

</div>
```

Comment: Use [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) i.e. `if (select_artist.selectedIndex <= 0 )`

Comment: Try to use `<select name="select" id="select">`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `selectedIndex`;

```
function validate() {

    var select_artist = document.getElementById('artistselect');
    if (select_artist.selectedIndex < 1) {
        alert("You need to choose an artist");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, you are trying to get the selected option by using div element. Set id attribute for `select` element instead.

```
<select name="select" id = "artistselect">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validate() {
   var select_artist = document.getElementById('select');
   if(select_artist.selectedIndex ==  0)
     alert("You need to choose an artist")
}
```

```html
<div id="artist"> 
     <p>Select an Artist:
<select id="select" onchange="validate()"> 
    <option>Choose Artist</option>
 <option >Bobby Smith</option>
    <option>The Vibes</option>
    <option>Kids of Rock</option>
</select>
</div>
```